# Cannot save Shipment in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipment

While creating an invoice from `Magento` backend I got the error message -

```
Cannot save Shipment
```

And in the exception I got this this--

```
PDOException: There is no active transaction in `/home/mag/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:316`
    Stack trace:
    `0` `/home/mag/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(316): PDO->commit()`
`1``/home/mag/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(510): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_commit()
2 /home/mag/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(253): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->commit()
3 /home/mag/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/AbstractResource.php(74): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->commit()`

4 /home/mag/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Interceptor.php(323): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource->commit()

5 /home/mag/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Transaction.php(57): Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Interceptor->commit()

6 /home/mag/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Transaction.php(147): Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction->_commitTransaction()

7 /home/mag/public_html/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save.php(79): Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction->save()
```

Comment: I am facing same issue still not getting success.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by [shaktivelp](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14110#issuecomment-404737516)

This issue still exists with the magento2.2.2 configurable product with child simple. And the below exception has been generated.

[2018-07-13 06:10:17] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 2999 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 2999 at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} [].

Kindly check about it and give me some updates.

For now i had added this as an fix:(/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php)

```
    case 'longtext':
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = json_encode($value);
        }
        $value  = (string)$value;
        if ($column['NULLABLE'] && $value == '') {
            $value = null;
        }
        break;
```